# Installation with no ISO

Tags: installation, iso

I would like to ask two questions about

1. installation with no iso and
2. can some  Linux-version be favoured gamewise, please.

I do want (perhaps an office type) Linux, might be Ubuntu (or Xubuntu? or equal) with one of the best available capasity for netgame that puts strain (as netgames usually  does) on especially the comp's video capasities (in this case it's "Ryzom" btw.). Which one of the Linux-versioons should i choose (ie. anything special about the different Linux-systems playwise)?

I can't use an iso but my machine works atm. (with a functioning OS, Win XP) that i thought i would replace with a new Linux. My old dvd-reader is not working (on my - now old - machine which is from 2011 iirc. It had - btw. Win7 working). I have considered especially Xubuntu ver. 12? I tried booting it from an USB-port but LiLi says: Error, no pae?? (questionmarks because the comp is not very old). I can d/l directly to the disk with plenty of room - which should solve the issue, I think.

Comment: What CPU does it have that PAE isn't supported?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one computer, it is possible to install without physical media by booting over the network using PXE. It's not necessarily an easy process, but quite satisfying and good for learning if you're willing to see it through. Here are some of the references that I used (please excuse the sites, the other computer was an old MacBook):

- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100501044411838
- https://wiki.koeln.ccc.de/index.php/Ubuntu_PXE_Install